# SharePoint 2010 Update Solution

Tags: 2010

I have changed Global Resource files in SharrePoint Package and some code (logic), nothing else was changed.
Should I use command **Update-SPSolution** to update my package or is it better to retract solution, remove, add new updated package and deploy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did not change the type of deployment (i.e. from Global to Web Application or vice-versa) using Update-SPSolution is fine.

If you changed from being globally deployed to being deployed to specific web applications or vice-versa, you would need to Uninstall, Remove, and then Add, and Deploy again.

Comment: I've also found that if (for whatever reason) you have renamed a feature folder, you'll need to uninstall/remove/add/deploy.